# When to Use C#9 Records

Tags: c#, immutability, language-design, c#-9.0, c#-record-type

C#9 was [officially announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/) a couple days ago, and one of the biggest additions to the language is the new "record" type using the `data` keyword. This new feature feels very similar to the [readonly structs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-in-modifier-and-the-readonly-structs-in-c/) of C#7.2, so I'm confused why one would use one over the other. Specifically:

1. Why would one use a `data struct` over a `readonly struct`? Are these not exactly the same thing?
2. Can one declare a `data readonly struct`? Wouldn't that be redundant?
3. Why would one use a `data class` over a `readonly struct`? They both achieve immutability and value-type equality, so is it just a question of performance (heap allocation vs copying when passed as a parameter)?

Bonus points: I could use some help understanding why "records change the defaults of what a simple member declaration...means"? I've been around enough enterprise code to anticipate giant data classes with dozens of members, where an inexperienced programmer will see `string FirstName;` and not think to scroll up to look for a `data` keyword, assuming that its a private field, not a publicly accessible property!

Comment: As far as #3 goes, a `data class` supports inheritance where a `readonly struct` does not.  If `data class`es have similar perf behavior and are stack allocated like structs, but having inheritance then I want them to have strongly typed variants of structs (think vectors in different reference frames).

Comment: Why not make structs inheritable instead of adding entire new denizen to the language? I also want to know developers' opinions, so maybe the OP should paste this onto Reddit seeing that StackOverflow doesn't want to allow this question?

Comment: #1: Yeah, let's ignore all the new syntax that ONLY applies to data records ;)

Comment: Until they actually release C# 9 I wouldn't take any "announcement" as anything other than "we hope to". They "announced" a lot of things for both C# 7 and 8 that were never released either, some of them are in this C# 9 "announcement". So forgive me for not holding my breath.

Comment: @lamont Good point about inheritance. My guess is that records will _not_ be stack-allocated, because they are classes, but then I have no idea for sure. Hopefully MS will provide some guidance on which declaration should be the preferred "default" for immutable data, kinda like how they [recommended classes over structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) back in the day.

Comment: Have look on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64828780/4553982)