# Can I use C# 9 records as IOptions?

Tags: c#, record, c#-9.0

I have just started playing around with C# 9 and .NET 5.0, specifically the new `record` construct. I find I have a lot of excellent use cases for the shorthand syntax of the record types.

One of the use cases I've considered was using a `record` for the dto in `IOptions<>`, instead of regular classes, for ASP.NET Core applications. These option classes are usually quite plain so I thought it would be a perfect fit, but it seems I cannot get it to work easily, since configuring the application using `IOptions<>` requires the object to have a parameterless constructor.

```cs
public record MyOptions(string OptionA, int OptionB);

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyOptions)));
    }
...
}

public class MyController : Controller 
{
    private readonly MyOptions _options;
    public MyController(IOptions<MyOptions> options) {
        _options = options.Value;  // This throws an exception at runtime
    }
}
```

The example above throws the following exception when attempting to access the `IOption<>.Value` property:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for type 'AcmeSolution.MyOptions'.'

Is there any way to configure the `IOptions` configuration system to deserialize the options using the record's constructor instead of requiring a parameterless constructor?

I could use the longhand syntax for the records, but then there's really no benefit over using a class.

Answer (score 20):

> Is there any way to configure the IOptions configuration system to deserialize the options using the record's constructor instead of requiring a parameterless constructor?

No, in general ASP.Net Core uses a lot of run-time type instancing, which requires constructor calls that are known beforehand, and in this case it requires a constructor with no arguments.

You can however make your record class have a parameter-less constructor:

```
public record MyOptions(string OptionA, int OptionB)
{
    public MyOptions(): this(default, default) {}
}
```

Is it worth it? Eh. Up to you. It's no worse than a regular class, performance-wise, so go with whatever you find clearer!

Edit: alternatively, you should be able to use this form:

```
public record MyOptions(string OptionA = default, int OptionB = default);
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to get very far with this though, because `record` properties are defined as `{get; init;}`, ie they're not settable. It depends how ASP.Net Core writes to these things and how far they can force them to be set through reflection, but at least conceptually records are immutable.

Comment: I am not able to make to short form working, can you confirm it is working ?

Comment: You mean the alternative? No, but it should logically. The first one works as advertised though, right?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. The Microsoft documentation uses a record in their very first example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options

Comment: @Blindy `init` is only relevant at compile-time. At runtime, it's just a normal setter, probably decorated with an attribute that lets the *compiler* know it's an `init`-only property. I don't think it's even possible for ASP.Net Core to be *un*able to set `init`-only properties.

Comment: The `public record MyOptions(string OptionA = default, int OptionB = default);` seems not working.

Answer (score 15):

**C# 10**

I know the question specifically references C# 9, but if you're living in the present, which I suspect most of you are, this works as expected with C# 10 (ASP.NET Core 6):

```
public record MyOptions
{
  public string MyProperty { get; init; }
}

// ...

builder.Services.Configure<MyOptions>(builder.Configuration);
```

Comment: It works indeed. I just wonder if this is documented somewhere since I cannot find anything mentioning it's possible. Probably it works just "by accident" since `init` setter is compiled similarly to "normal" setter just with some [additional metadata](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAsAKAG4EMBOACA9rgLy4B2ApgO64DyADsGPqQM64Deau3uAgnWACq2CMVwAiAK4jxULj35gA0uQCeY8QGs1snrjQBfANxp8AOkXCIJKSICM4k6gD0z84pXqb21QCZHaGgAAgDMuEG+tAxMrGicqHqh4XYADHwCVhy4AObkwEa4LHkFBhoBCTxJQanpympZufm4YKRgTaU25QZAA=) for compiler to prevent setting it after construction. Which is fine I guess...

Comment: what's the advantage of this over a class? I suspect I can just replace the `record` keyword above with `class` and nothing changes?

Comment: @Tolu, the advantages and disadvantages of `class`, `struct`, and `record` will depend on your use case. You might find the accepted answer on this SO question useful: [When to use record vs class vs struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64816714/when-to-use-record-vs-class-vs-struct).

Comment: @Tolu, the biggest difference is that `records` have Value Equality.

Answer (score -4):

Add parameter less constructor

public MyOptions() {}