# Why editing a datagrid in the GUI "invisibly" selects row. WPF C# 9.0

Tags: wpf, datagrid, c#-9.0

My problem is following:
I have a datagrid element which is bound to an underlying data structure.
CanUserDeleteRows property is set to "True"
Now when I edit an element in a row it seems that it is "invisibly" selected, which is a problem, because when I delete another row by pressing "delete" key the previously edited row is deleted as well.

What is an underlying issue and how to fix?

Comment: This is the expected behavior.
A line is highlighted when you click on it, or if the keyboard focus moves to it.
As you edit its contents, it becomes selected accordingly.

Comment: But you cannot see that it was selected and you cannot unselect it

Comment: Also suppose you edit all the rows and then decide delete one of them, then all the rows will be deleted and there is no indication that all rows are selected. I think it is hardly the expected behaviour.

Comment: It depends on how you implemented it all.
What does "not see" mean?
That is, it is not highlighted in blue?
Have you changed the style or template?
What is the state of the IsSelected property of the DataGrid row?
What exactly are you deleting?
One item from SelectedItem or list from SelectedItems?
How do you create and modify the collection represented by the DataGrid?
Is it an observable collection, or a bindable collection, or a DataTable?

Comment: It will be much easier to understand your problem if you supplement the question with minimal code demonstrating the problem and show some screenshots to explain the essence.

Comment: I tried  to reproduce this on a very simple code with ObservableCollection and it works as expected,  so clearly it's something wrong/unusual with my code. I'll keep working on isolating the issue and will give more information later.

Comment: Have you changed any brushes, set style on a datagrid row so the background brush is transparent or doesn't change? Or set background on datagrid cell so you can't see the row background beneath?

Comment: No I didn't change any style

Comment: If the question would not be legitimate it would be close-voted, closed and probably deleted. If the answer were not legitimate it would be flagged and deleted. So you can see that (probably) nobody considered question or answer not legitimate. Your discussion of this does not help with the question and I recommend to remove it. Downvotes (even if anonymous) are a different thing. If one user thinks that your question is not according to [ask] or that the answer is not according to [answer] they will probably downvote. (downvotes not by me by the way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,
I think I've found the issue, after trying to reproduce the problem, the only difference left between my simple data structure was that I've used *record* instead of *class*.
It seems that this is probably a bug that when using a *record* instead of *class*, the edited item is not "unselected".
I suppose I will stick using a *class* and not experimenting with new features like *record*